# Expected area of the union of two and three circles

Tags: probability, geometry, circles

I have done the part of two circles.
Suppose that there are two intersecting circles with radius **R**.
And let the distance between the center of two circles is **D**.(0$\le$D$\le$2R)

The intersection of two circles $A_{intersection}$ is given by $2R^2cos^{-1}\left(\frac{D}{2R}\right)-\frac{D}{2}\sqrt{4R^2-D^2}$.

Therefore, the union $A_{union}$ is given by $2R^2\pi-\frac{A_{intersection}}{2}$

And the probability **P** that the distance between the center of two circles is **D** is given by $\frac{2\pi D}{(2R)^2\pi}$.

The expected area of the union of two circles is $\int_{0}^{2R} P\times A_{union} dD$

I am wondering that is it correct?
And how do i calculate the union of three circles?

Comment: I think your probability is incorrect. As for doing the 3-circle case, here's a hint: consider two at a time and use the 2-circle result you already have. Also, to compute the probability, think of the events 'circle 1 intercepts circle 2', 'circle 1 intercepts circle 3', and 'circle 2 intercepts circle 3', then use conditional probabilities.

Comment: How do i compute the probability of 'circle 1,2,3 intercepts each other'? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If $B,C,D\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ have well defined area then: $$A_{B\cup C}=A_B+A_C-A_{B\cap C}$$

(not $\dots-\frac{A_{B\cap C}}{2}$ as you seem to think)

and (concerning your question about $3$ circles):

$$A_{B\cup C\cup D}=A_B+A_C+A_D-A_{B\cap C}-A_{C\cap D}-A_{B\cap D}+A_{B\cap C\cap D}$$

You are probably are dealing with a random variable $D$ that is uniformly distributed over interval $(0,2R)$.

What you (incorrectly) call "probability" is the PDF (*Probability Distribution Function*) of $D$: a function prescribed by $x\mapsto\frac{2\pi x}{(2R^2)\pi}=\frac{x}{2R^2}$ on $(0,2R)$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. Can you plz elaborate on PDF about 3 circles.

Comment: I suspect that you are dealing then with $3$ circles all with radius $R$ s.t. the centers form an equilateral triangle and have mutual distance $D$. Again $D$ will be uniformly distributed over $(0,2R)$ so nothing changes when it comes to the PDF of it. Advice: first do it for $R=1$ just to avoid the (annoying) parameter. Multiplying afterwards with $R^2$ gives you the general result.